# How can one integrate $\int\frac{1}{(x+1)^4(x^2+1)} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

> How can one integrate $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{(x+1)^4(x^2+1)}\  dx$?

**Attempt**:

I tried [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) (PFD) and got lost. The method of [u-substitution](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-integration-new/ab-6-9/a/review-applying-u-substitution) didn't work for me either.

What else can I do? Can one calculate the integral without PFD?

Comment: I don't know if there another more or less elementary way to integrate that thing without partial fractions, but I think it is unlikely it'll be much easier than that...

Comment: *Mathematica* gives: $-\frac{3 x^2+9 x+3 (x+1)^3 \tan ^{-1}(x)+8}{12 (x+1)^3}$.

Comment: Well, just as said: that substitution requires from you to find out what $\;1+x\;$ and $\;1+x^2\;$ is in terms of $\;t\;$ . Not sure how faster/easier that is instead of partial fractions from the beginning. Perhaps it is just a matter of getting used to this or that.

Comment: @Don. It can be done without PFD. See my answer below. Couple of u-subs and backsubs, rest is Algebra.

Comment: @imranfat And still you need some basic rational functions' integration to do it, including polynomial division....As said, I'm not sure how fast those methods are than usual PF's ...

Comment: @Don. That's true. My approach is just to avoid PFD, but I don't think it is quicker at all. The OP wanted a method without PFD but in his integral, I am not sure why. On the other hand, the u-sub x=1/t is very effective where a numerator is a constant and the denominator is, say x^9-x. Then PFD would be brutal. So my u-sub method is a method that one should have in his "back pocket", hence my post.

Comment: where are you getting lost with the partial fractions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a secure and faster method when the fraction has a  pole  of comparatively high order:

1. If the pole is not $0$, as is the case here, perform the substitution $u=x+1$ and express the other factors in function  of $u$. We have to take care of $x^2+1$. The method of successive divisions yields $x^2+1=u^2-2u+2$, so we have
   $$\frac 1{(x+1)^4(x^2+1)}=\frac1{u^4}\cdot\frac 1{2-2u+u^2}.$$
2. Perform the division of $1$ by $2-2u+u^2$ *along increasing powers of $u$*, up to order $4$:
   $$\begin{array}{r}
   \phantom{\frac12}\\
   \phantom{u}\\
   2-2u+u^2\Big(
   \end{array}\begin{array}[t]{&&rr@{}rrrrr}
    \frac12&{}+\frac 12 u&{}+\frac 14u^2 \\
   %\hline
   1 \\
   -1&{}+u&{}-\frac12u^2 \\\hline
   &u&{}-\frac12u^2 \\
   &-u& +u^2 &{}-\frac12u^3\\
   \hline
   &&&\frac12u^2&{}-\frac12u^3 \\
   &&&-\frac12u^2&{}+\frac12u^3&-\frac14u^4  \\
   \hline
   &&&&&-\frac14u^4  
   \end{array} $$
3. This yields the equality:
   $$1=(2-2u+u^2)\bigl(\tfrac12+\tfrac 12 u+\tfrac 14u^2\bigr)-\tfrac14u^4,$$
   whence the partial fractions decomposition:

$$\frac 1{u^4(2-2u+u^2)}=\frac1{2u^4}+\frac 1{2u^3} u+\frac 1{4u^2}-\frac1{4(2-2u+u^2)},$$
or with $x$ :
$$\frac 1{(x+1)^4(x^2+1)}=\frac1{2(x+1)^4}+\frac 1{2(x+1)^3} +\frac 1{4(x+1)^2}-\frac1{4(x^2+1)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

We use a variant of the [Heaviside method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method). Shift by one and consider

$$\frac{1}{z^4(z^2-2z+2)}\text{.}$$
Develop $1/(z^2-2z+2)$ in series about $z=0$, keeping the remainder exactly as you go:
$$\frac{1}{z^2-2z+2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{4}-\frac{z^4}{4(z^2-2z+2)}\text{.}$$
Then
$$\frac{1}{z^4(z^2-2z+2)}=\frac{2 + 2z + z^2}{4z^4}-\frac{1}{4(z^2-2z+2)}\text{.}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: How exactly does Heaviside method work and where can I read up on it?

Comment: @StackUpPhysics [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method).

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

This can actually be done with very elementary math.

Step 1: Perform $u$-sub $x+1=t$,

step 2: Perform u-sub $t=\frac{1}{z}$. The integral becomes $\int\frac{-z^4}{2z^2-2z+1} dz$ upon which long division can be performed.

You will have to integrate couple of polynomial terms, you will also  get a natural log and a basic arctangent (after completing the square on $2z^2-2z+1$). Then you need to backsub. A bit of annoying algebra, but very elementary in terms of calculus, and no partial fraction decomposition.